# Is there any data-mining/text-mining/machine learning techniques to find the most appropriate Tags for a given document

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, tagging, text-mining

Say I have a huge set of documents represented in relational Table with columns

```
    ID (unique identifier)
    Title (255 characters)
    Description (5000 characters)
    Category (predefined meta-data )
    Additional Notes (1000 characters )
```

I would like to add one or more Tags for each row in the document table. Here Tags refer to a word or a group of words that tells readers what a document is about.

Is there any data-mining/text-mining/machine learning techniques or approach that will help me to find the most appropriate Tags for a given document without human interference.

Comment: This is way to broad question. There are dozens if not hundreads of such methods, and many of them will show up just by googling "automatic document tagging" or "tag suggesting algorithm".

Comment: maybe look at multilabel classifications? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simple possible approaches: for a given document calculate [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) measure for every word and choose top-N words as tags (or cut candidates by some threshold).
Also in your case it's reasonable to use empirical boosting coefficients for words in the Title and Category fields.